# How to disable vertical scrolling on mobile on a 100vh page?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with vertical scrolling on mobile devices, the page scrolls horizontally and the body height is set to 100vh, however i still can scroll down on mobile devices and it just messes up my content and shows some weird "loading" div

```
body{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 170vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

How it looks after scrolling down:
[image: 1]
how it should look:
[image: 2]

Comment: did you try adding height: 100vh, instead of max-height: 100vh;

Comment: yes, nothing changed :(

Comment: body{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
I think this will fix it too....

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `height: 100vh` instead of max-height and add `position: relative` like this:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}


/** CSS BELOW IS JUST FOR SHOW **/

div {
  background: grey;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vh
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also, there is no need for the `overflow-x`. It will be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've found the solution! adding !important fixed the issue

```
body{
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    width: 170vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body{ 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

I think this will fix it too....